# Healthy worker bias problem

Tags: inference, confounding

[From here (page 83)](https://cdn1.sph.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1268/2019/11/ci_hernanrobins_10nov19.pdf), The effect of working as a firefighter **A** on the risk of death **Y** will be confounded if “being physically fit” **L** is a cause of both **being an active firefighter** and having a lower **mortality risk**. This confounding bias is often referred to as a **healthy worker bias**.

**But, what's the problem?** Why can't we just subdivide firemen into categories by their physical strength and study the **mortality risk** of each group separately. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what you should do to eliminate the healthy worker bias. Stratification on a confounder (which is what you described) eliminates the bias due to the confounder. The problem is when you don't stratify on the confounder, in which case the bias remains. The reason this is an interesting phenomenon is that one might not immediately think that a confounder was at play here. The simple unadjusted association between working and mortality is biased, but the adjusted association (i.e., adjusted through stratification) is unbiased. This example motivates the need for an understanding of causality, bias due to causal misspecification, and how to eliminate bias through analysis in epidemiology. Without thinking about the common causes of working and mortality, the bias such a common cause induces in the association, and the methods of adjusting for that common cause, the observed phenomon is unexpected and unexplained.

Comment: Thanks! And what if we don't have enough data to use stratification, does it mean that we won't be able to eliminate bias?

Comment: That's right. There are several ways to reduce bias due to confounding; one is to measure and adjust for the confounder, and another is to find what's called an instrument, which is a variable with special properties that when used in a certain way eliminates bias due to confounding. Without either of these, it may be possible to put bounds on the true relationship or to assess how strong the confounding would have to be to reverse the observed association.